# Printing an aligned banner?

Tags: ruby, pretty-print

I am wondering if there is some ruby print function that will allow me to print a string such that it is centered and padded with whitespace. I need to make banners for a program with different texts like this:

```
<!-- ======================================================================= --> 
<!--                     Whatever text is in the string....                  --> 
<!-- ======================================================================= -->
```

I actually found a way to do this for a string that is <= 90 - 2 characters.. :

```
len = 90
msg = "random_string" 

str = msg.center( msg.length + (len - msg.length) )
print "<!-- " + str +  "-->"
```

but now I want to support the possiblity that the message can be of a size greater than 90 and allow me to continue on a new line if that is the case. Even better if it can avoid splitting words (logic starts getting complex there). Any ideas, or an existing gem/library to do this?

Thanks,
Ted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Revised:** Here's a revised answer, hopefully this more along the lines you were thinking. It assumes you have the Unix tool `fmt` to size the lines right. This could probably be implemented in Ruby with a little bit of work.

```
msg = <<MSG_END
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Nunc tincidunt libero eget justo convallis tincidunt. Curabitur
augue arcu, eleifend sit amet porttitor a, porttitor ac purus.
Vivamus non leo nulla, vel pulvinar urna. Cum sociis natoque penatibus
et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. In at purus
risus. Maecenas imperdiet commodo turpis ullamcorper porttitor. Sed
imperdiet porta rutrum. Proin sodales lorem et dui mattis accumsan.
Etiam fermentum magna sed justo tristique commodo. Nulla at purus
in leo dignissim ultrices. Mauris tincidunt egestas nunc, sit amet
placerat mauris hendrerit at. Vestibulum at vestibulum ante.
MSG_END

cols = 60 - 9 # subtract 9 to account for the extra `<!-- ` and ` -->`

sized = `echo '#{msg}' | fmt -w #{cols}`

centered = sized.split("\n").map do |l|
   "<!-- #{l.center(cols)} -->\n"
end

puts centered
```

Returns:

```
<!-- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing  -->
<!--  elit.  Nunc tincidunt libero eget justo convallis  -->
<!-- tincidunt. Curabitur augue arcu, eleifend sit amet  -->
<!--  porttitor a, porttitor ac purus.  Vivamus non leo  -->
<!--    nulla, vel pulvinar urna. Cum sociis natoque     -->
<!-- penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur -->
<!--     ridiculus mus. In at purus risus. Maecenas      -->
<!-- imperdiet commodo turpis ullamcorper porttitor. Sed -->
<!-- imperdiet porta rutrum. Proin sodales lorem et dui  -->
<!--  mattis accumsan.  Etiam fermentum magna sed justo  -->
<!-- tristique commodo. Nulla at purus in leo dignissim  -->
<!--  ultrices. Mauris tincidunt egestas nunc, sit amet  -->
<!--     placerat mauris hendrerit at. Vestibulum at     -->
<!--                  vestibulum ante.                   -->
```

Comment: It doesn't do quite what I want it to do. It doesn't align to the center from the second line on.

Comment: I revised my answer above, hopefully this is more along the lines your were thinking.